# boost::asio::connect reports success on wrong subnet

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio, vpn

Using Boost v1.74:

```
int main()
{
    auto ctx = boost::asio::io_context{};
    auto socket = boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket{ctx};
    auto ep = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint{
                     boost::asio::ip::make_address_v4("192.168.0.52"),
                     80};
    boost::asio::connect(socket, std::array{std::move(ep)});

    std::cout << "Success!" << std::endl;
}
```

The IP address of my machine on my local network is `192.168.0.31/24`, and so trying to connect to a non-existent address in the same subnet with the above code gives:

```
10:24:55: Starting /home/cmannett85/workspace/build-scratch-Desktop-Debug/scratch ...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>'
  what():  connect: No route to host
10:24:59: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

This is all expected.  If I change the bottom octet of the subnet in the address (e.g. `192.168.1.52`), then the app just waits for a few minutes - *presumably* because it sent messages to any routers to see if they own the requested subnet.  There aren't any routers on my network, so it eventually times out:

```
10:27:39: Starting /home/cmannett85/workspace/build-scratch-Desktop-Debug/scratch ...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>'
  what():  connect: Connection timed out
10:29:49: The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Again, as expected.  If I change the *next* octet (e.g. `192.167.0.52`) instead, I would expect this to behave exactly the same as it is an equally unknown subnet as the previous.  But it suceeds!

```
10:31:22: Starting /home/cmannett85/workspace/build-scratch-Desktop-Debug/scratch ...
Success!
```

This address is definitely not on my network:

```
$ ping 192.167.0.52
PING 192.167.0.52 (192.167.0.52) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.167.0.52 ping statistics ---
17 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 16368ms
```

So why is the code reporting that it is connected?  And why is changing the second octet different to the third?

Comment: Perhaps you should change the "update" to an answer. That way, it might actually prove useful to others

Comment: @sehe because although it is the cause, I have no idea *why*.  Why would the VPN server I'm tunnelled to 'trick' the OS into thinking it has connected?

Comment: maybe something is really available on 192.168.0.52? ICMP (ping) can be blocked by the firewall but TCP connections could be still available. better check with curl for instance `curl -v http://192.168.0.52` or maybe just try to open `http://192.168.0.52` in the browser.

Comment: @dewaffled good call, curl showed that something is completing the TCP handshake, but can't handle the HTTP request, and so closes the connection after a few minutes.

Comment: @sehe I don't think I'll learn anything beyond this, so I'll do what you suggest and turn the update section into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any IP address of the form 192.168.xx.xx is a non-internet-routable network. This means no internet routers will route it. So the only way packets get routed off your subnet is if you configure a route on your own router or host. 192.167.xx.xx is an internet routable network, Presumable there is a host out there on the internet that uses the address you specified. So if you can connect your host to the internet, some internet router will get your packet to the address specified.

Answer (score 1):

It's something related to my VPN.  I didn't think it was relevant as the tunnel address is `10.17.0.60/16`, but disabling it makes the above code work as expected.

Thanks to a suggestion by @dewaffled, Curl is showing that there is *something* on the otherside of this connection that is completing the TCP handshake, but after a timeout of a few minutes closes the connection.

```
$ curl -v http://192.167.0.52
*   Trying 192.167.0.52:80...
* Connected to 192.167.0.52 (192.167.0.52) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.167.0.52
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

I know nothing about how VPNs work, but I suspect this is an implementation detail of my particular provider.  Hopefully this 'answer' will limit confusion for anyone else!